# Как правильно записать вывод для функции с массивом, не получается

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Функция проверяет наличие элемента value  в массиве array и должна вернуть true, если элемент есть в массиве и false  - если не найден. Почему ничего не выводит?

```js
function includes (array, value) {
  var result = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (array[i] === value) {
      resalt = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
//var array = [4,7,44,8,5];
//var value = 7;

var someArray = [12, 'str', 234, true];
includes (someArray, 234);
```

Comment: А куда должно вывести?) Используйте `console.log(includes(someArray, 234));` для вывода в консоль. И вообще, не правильно после названия функции ставить пробел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас была ошибка в названии переменной:

```js
resalt = true; // должно быть result = true;
```

2. Вы никуда не выводили, для это нужно использовать допустим `console.log`.

(После названий функций пробелы обычно не ставят.)

```js
function includes(array, value) {
  var result = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === value) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
//var array = [4,7,44,8,5];
//var value = 7;

var someArray = [12, 'str', 234, true];
console.log(includes(someArray, 234));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function includes (array, value) {
  let result = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (array[i] === value) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const someArray = [12, 'str', 234, true];
const resultFuncIncludes = includes(someArray, 234);
console.log(resultFuncIncludes);
```